# Pulse to sine with the same frequency

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, signal-processing

I have a pulse signal with frequency f(t)
And i want to generate from it a sine signal with frequency f(t)
(f(t) doesn't vary a lot in time)
Is there a method to do it directly with a function generator ?
If no, How can i acheive this ?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more on-topic on  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't know about that website. i will post it there.

Comment: Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com ; the generic answer is "use a PLL" but maybe if you're lucky your function generator has a synchronization input

Comment: ah! I just answered this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93207/pulse-signal-to-sine-signal-with-the-same-frequency/93209#93209 ; it is very welcome next time when you cross-link when posting the same question in multiple places.